# VALIDAR INPUT JVSCRIPT

Tags: php

estoy intentando validar un input de javascrit pero no me da el resultado que quiero.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar"  id="q" style="position:inherit;" required/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="load(1);">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </button>
                            </span>
```

y este es el jvscript

```
<script>
function load(page){
  var elemento = document.getElementById("q").value
  if (elemento == ""){
    alert("Debes llenar el campo")
    return false
  }else {
    var query=$("#q").val();
        var per_page=5;
        var parametros = {"action":"ajax","page":page,'query':query,'per_page':per_page};
        $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax/listar_productos.php',
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#loader").html("Cargando...");
          },
            success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loader").html("");
            }
        })
    }
    }
   }
```

quiero que no se active la busqueda si no ingresa nada, porque me pasa que si el input esta vacio y clickeo buscar, hace la busqueda buscando valor 0 o null

anteriomente tenia solamente el buscador y siempre estaba activo

```
function load(page){
        var query=$("#q").val();
        var per_page=5;
        var parametros = {"action":"ajax","page":page,'query':query,'per_page':per_page};
        $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax/listar_productos.php',
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#loader").html("Cargando...");
          },
            success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loader").html("");
            }
        })
    }
```

y quise validarlo con otro script

```
function validar() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("q").value
  if (elemento == ""){
    alert("Debes llenar el campo")
    return false
  }else {
    alert("Genial el valor es: "+elemento)
    return false
  }
}
```

lo valida, muestra las alertas, pero hace igualmente las busquedas

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código y la lógina es correcta, únicamente sobra una llave en la función completa, no sé si puede ser un error al copiar. Sólo es necesario recoger el valor de q una vez al inicio de la función. 
Dejo un ejemplo.

```js
function load(page){
  var query=$("#q").val();
  if (query == ""){
    alert("Debes llenar el campo");
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("buscar " + query);    
    //hacer resto de procesos
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar"  id="q" style="position:inherit;" required/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="load(1);">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Buscar
</button>
</span>
```